# Is it OK to do this manipulation at the partition function level? (auxiliary fields in quadratic gravity)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity, partition-function, cosmological-constant, linearized-theory

**Background**

I am working with the following action in the Euclidean signature ($C^2$ is the Weyl quadratic term):
\begin{equation}
S_B = -\frac{1}{2\kappa^2}\int d^4x\sqrt{g}\left(2\Lambda_C+\zeta R-\frac{1}{2m_\chi^2} C^2-\frac{1}{6}\xi R^2\right), \tag{1}
\end{equation}
with $\Lambda_C<0$ and the other constants are positive. After using two auxiliary fields $\phi$ and $\chi_{\mu \nu}$, treating the $R^2$ term à la Starobinsky and using the redefinition $g_{\mu \nu} \leadsto g_{\mu \nu}+2\kappa \chi_{\mu \nu}$, one finds that $(1)$ is transformed into:
\begin{align}
S_B=-\frac{1}{2\kappa^2}\int d^4x\sqrt{g} \left( R-\kappa^2 g^{\mu \nu}\partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi -V_E(\phi)\right)-S^E_\text{FP}(\chi,m_\chi)+\int d^4x \sqrt{g}\chi_{\mu \nu} T_\phi^{\mu \nu}+S^{>2}(g,\chi),\tag{2}
\end{align}
with $S^E_\text{FP}$ the Euclidean Fierz-Pauli action with mass $m_\chi$, $S^{>2}$ an interaction term containing combinations of three fields ($\chi \chi R$) and more, and the euclidean potential $V_E$ is:
\begin{equation}
V_E(\phi)=\frac{3}{2\xi}\left(1+\epsilon e^{-\frac{\kappa}{\sqrt{6}}\phi}\right)-2\Lambda_C \frac{1}{\zeta^2}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\kappa \phi}. \tag{3}
\end{equation}
$\epsilon$ is just a sign indicating if we are in Euclidean signature ($\epsilon = +1$) or in Lorentzian signature ($\epsilon=-1$). The parameters of the potential are *not* fine tuned so that its minimum in Lorentzian signature is $0$.

**The trick**

Now, as you can see $(3)$ contains the cosmological constant term, and expanding the potential in powers of $\kappa \phi$ one can eventually extract this term. But when we construct the partition function
\begin{equation}
Z= \int \mathcal{D}g\mathcal{D}\chi \mathcal{D}\phi\,e^{-S_B}, \tag{4}
\end{equation}
we can introduce a source $J$ such that
\begin{equation}
Z = \left. \int \mathcal{D}g\,e^{-\int d^4x \sqrt{g} V_E\left(\frac{-\delta}{\delta J}\right)}\int\mathcal{D}\chi \mathcal{D}\phi\,e^{-S_B+\int d^4x \sqrt{g}( V_E(\phi)+J\phi)} \right|_{J=0}. \tag{5}
\end{equation}
Then, expanding the metric around flat space gives:
\begin{equation}
Z \sim \left. e^{-\int d^4x \sqrt{\det\left( \delta_{\mu \nu}+2\kappa \frac{-\delta}{\delta T_1^{\mu \nu}} \right)} V_E\left(\frac{-\delta}{\delta J}\right)}\int \mathcal{D}h\mathcal{D}\chi \mathcal{D}\phi\,e^{-S^\text{quad}_B+\int d^4x \left[\sqrt{\det(\delta_{\mu \nu}+2\kappa h_{\mu \nu})}(V_E(\phi)+J\phi)+T_1^{\mu \nu}h_{\mu \nu}\right]} \right|_{J,T_1=0}, \tag{6}
\end{equation}
where we have diregarded all the higher order terms in $S_B$ and may do so for  such terms arising from $\sqrt{\det(\delta_{\mu \nu}+2\kappa h_{\mu \nu})}$.

**Question**

Is it OK to do so at the partition function level? In particular, will the physics arising from the Feynman diagrams given by this partition function be in accordance with the fact that one has still a cosmological constant?